# Why this query is to slow in mysql

Tags: mysql, performance

I try to improve this query but I do not made successefully. I use a some left join and subquerys (I don't know another form) We try to get all bookings from users with certain status and the number of bookings multiples related with this booking and get from the log user the origin. The query is slow even if use a limit clausure. I Appreciate all the help can you give me.

This is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.uneaque_id, b.id, b.status, b.route_status, b.username, b.purpose, b.transfer, b.pickup_date, b.pickup_time, b.return_time, b.amount, b.default_location, b.start_address_route_comments, b.start_address_route, b.end_address_route_comments, b.end_address_route, u1.first_name, u1.last_name, b.transaction_Id, b.manual_payment, mr.AddressCount, lu.origin 
        FROM bookingdetails b 
        LEFT JOIN log_users lu ON lu.uneaque_id = b.uneaque_id AND lu.command_type = 'NEW BOOKING' 
        LEFT JOIN ( 
            SELECT booking_id, COUNT(*) AS AddressCount FROM booking_multiple_rides GROUP BY booking_id
        ) mr ON b.id = mr.booking_id,
        userdetails u1 WHERE b.username = u1.email 
        AND u1.user_status IN ('Active', 'Blocked', 'Not_Active')
        AND b.default_location = 1
```

PD: Sorry for my english.

Comment: It's very hard to tell what the problem might be based on what you've posted because nobody knows the structure of the tables referred to in your query. At a guess, you might need some indexes/foreign keys on the columns joining the tables mentioned in the query. E.g. Is u1.user_status an enum or a varchar field?

Comment: Why, instead of downvote the question, you let me know this is a "dumb" question???

Comment: thanks a lot @trapper_hag. All the fields in the query are indexes. The user_status is an enum field

Comment: @trapper_hag you are rigth, without the structure is hard to find out how improve the query. I can't post the structure, but if exists any possibility to check it out I will. Sorry for my english, btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a ON b.id = mr.booking_id, userdetails u1  WHERE
you should change with a proper inner join

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.uneaque_id
    , b.id, b.status
    , b.route_status
    , b.username
    , b.purpose
    , b.transfer
    , b.pickup_date
    , b.pickup_time
    , b.return_time
    , b.amount
    , b.default_location
    , b.start_address_route_comments
    , b.start_address_route
    , b.end_address_route_comments
    , b.end_address_route
    , u1.first_name
    , u1.last_name
    , b.transaction_Id
    , b.manual_payment
    , mr.AddressCount
    , lu.origin 
FROM bookingdetails b 
LEFT JOIN log_users lu ON lu.uneaque_id = b.uneaque_id AND lu.command_type = 'NEW BOOKING' 
LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT booking_id
          , COUNT(*) AS AddressCount 
          FROM booking_multiple_rides GROUP BY booking_id
) mr ON b.id = mr.booking_id
INNER JOIN userdetails u1 ON  b.username = u1.email 
AND u1.user_status IN ('Active', 'Blocked', 'Not_Active')
AND b.default_location = 1
```

and be sure you have proper index  on
table bookingdetails a composite index on   columns ( uneaque_id , id, default_location)

table  log_users a composite index  on  columns  (uneaque_id, command_type)
table  userdetails a cmposite index on  columns (email,user_status )

Comment: Thank you very much @scaisEdge. All fields in the query have indexes. Why do we need a composite index (This is due to my ignorance) I thought that if all the fields in the query have an index it would be enough

Comment: Because  a query can use just one index  for each table  and the use of a composite index is most selective then  a single column index  ..  overall a single column index can interfere with a composite index .. you should build index  based on your real query  (where and join ) need  not indexing all the column  without specific query criteria

Comment: Excelent @scaisEdge, thanks a lot for your reponse. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @AnibalMauricio   I am very pleased.  IN SO...the best way to show your appreciation is a fair rating for useful and / or accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Tip 1.

Hiding a derived table in a `LEFT JOIN` is a prescription for sluggishness.

Replace

```
mr.AddressCount
```

with

```
( SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM  booking_multiple_rides
            WHERE booking_id = b.id
            GROUP BY  booking_id ) AS AddressCount
```

and get rid of the `LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ... ) AS mr ON ..`

Tip 2  Use explicit `JOINs`, no the old-fashioned "comma-join":

```
JOiN userdetails u1
    ON  b.username = u1.email
```

This won't help performance but it will make things clearer.

Tip 3:  If you need an `INNER JOIN` (u1) after a `LEFT JOIN`, use parentheses.  Else, put the inner joins first, then the left joins.  This makes it easier to use, *but* may screw up the logic.

Tip 4:  Don't use `LEFT` unless you need it.  When you dont need it, it confuses the reader (and the Optimizer).  (Again, no performance change.)

Tip 5:  Why are you using `DISTINCT`?  That takes an extra pass over all the resultset.

If those do not help enough, then provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can critique the indexes.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks a lot for your response and your tips. It is very clear and helpful. Yeah, I think the distinct clause is not necessary. I could get rid of this. Let me try this tips. Thanks a lot for your help. Sorry for my english